# Apache and MySql datbase memory consumption issue with Django

Tags: memory, mysql, apache-http-server, django

I'm writing a relatively simple web-application as a learning project to learn Django, Apache, Mysql etc. in practice. It consists of a web flash/html5 client which makes two API-calls to Django Rest-Framework api once per second. One gets status of an object and another increments a counters in a Django model. In addition to this I have a Celery task which executes a code which modifies one of the models every second.

On my VPS I set up a Django served on Apache with MySql as a db. After I start all relevant process and the clients start to make request, the memory-usage spirals out of control and quickly reaches 512Mb which is my VPS' limit and Apache/MySql crashes. At the moment, three simultaneous clients are enough to cause the crash which is not acceptable.

I did some research today and tried to use this http://wiki.vpslink.com/Low_memory_MySQL_/_Apache_configurations and this https://serverfault.com/questions/21106/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-on-a-unix-webserver as a guide to limit the MPM settings of my server. I dropped the values from default ones to the ones in latter link with no clear effect. I also tried the skip-innodb trick but after adding that to my mysql conf I couldn't start my mysql-server at all.

Being a relatively beginner I'm a bit at loss now since I don't yet have much knowledge of the Apache configurations. Therefore I'd like to ask how I should proceed now and what configurations I should do considering my technology stack?

Finally, here is my current Apache config: http://pastebin.com/0agashnT
And since it is always possible that I have made a stupid errors in my Django code, here is the relevant code bits which are called when the client access the API and hen Celery task is executed:

Celery task:

```
    @periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=1))
def update_RocketModel():
    pushmodel = PushModel.objects.get()  #get amount of the latest pushes
    rocket = Rocket.objects.get()
    rocket.pushes = pushmodel.amount
    rocket.velocity += (pushmodel.force / rocket.mass) / 1000.0    #F=ma, m/s to km/s
    logger.debug("Velocity boost: result = %i" % ((pushmodel.force / rocket.mass) / 1000.0))

    rocket.distanceTraveled = rocket.distanceTraveled + rocket.velocity
    rocket.distanceFromSun = rocket.distanceFromSun + rocket.velocity

    #calculate ETA to the target
    try:
        target = CelestialObjectModel.objects.get(name=rocket.nextDestination)
        dist = target.distanceFromSun - rocket.distanceFromSun   #distance to the target
        rocket.estimatedTravelTime = dist / rocket.velocity

    except CelestialObjectModel.DoesNotExist:
        #we couldn't find the target Celestial-body, lets not modify the ETA
        pass

    #reset push model
    pushmodel.amount = 0
    pushmodel.force = 0
    pushmodel.save()

    rocket.save()
    #logger.info("Rocket updated")
```

A RestAPI-view which handles one request which modifies a model in db:

```
class PushesView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PushesView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pushes = PushModel.objects.first()
        serializer = PushSerializer(pushes, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data) #headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        entries = []
        entries.append(request.DATA)

        #take json-array of the pushes and take the forces:   
        pushList = request.DATA["pushes"]
        forceCount = 0
        for x in pushList:
            forceCount += x["push"]

        PushModel.objects.filter().update(amount=(F('amount')+len(pushList)))
        PushModel.objects.filter().update(force=(F('force')+forceCount))
        return Response("SUCCESS")
```